# php imap get connection failed error

Tags: php, imap

```
Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in /home/happy/public_html/source/imap/fet_mail_from_email_add.php on line 7
can't connect: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Connection timed out
```

my snippet is

> $mbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX",
>       "user@gmail.com","somesecretpassword")
>       or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

Comment: @Bharanikumar: I wouldn't publish my usernamer/password on the web

Comment: @Bharanikumar: also change your gmail password right **NOW**

Comment: yes..that's dummy password...

Comment: FYI - the script works fine for me

Comment: @Jason: normal he has a network problem, so it's not the script but his environment.

Comment: am running on live...not an local..if my guess is correct ur saying my internet connection problem....

Comment: Hi can u tell me snippet for simple imap connection(gmail,ymail)
please post working snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the error message point out there is a network timeout/connection failure happening.

Make sure any network equipment (Firewall, router with ACL, etc ...) don't disallow to connect to the TCP port 993.

You would probably make sure you can connect from the server to Gmail server using ssh and trying with telnet first, if that test is ok try with PHP.

Comment: Then i have to off the firewall

Comment: I wouldn't say turn it off but take a look if you can add the proper rule to connect to gmail.

Comment: hi..see am running this script in the live QA server...

Also my friend testing this in another system...

there also getting same error...

Comment: are you able to connect using any low level utility telnet netcat ?

Comment: My php script using imap_open() for gmail failed after I installed ConfigServer firewall. Under IPv4 Port Settings I had to add "993" to the list of ports for `TCP_OUT`. Now it works.